# AWS Cognito with and without custom signup and sign in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to integrate AWS cognito into my cloud infrastructure. 
I need it to let users access certain ALB routes and certain objects in s3 bucket behind cloudfront. This part seems easy with IAM rules.

The main difficulty is getting the users login and signup pages. I would have thought AWS would provide a login/signup page with the required info specified when I set up a pool but I can't find a tutorial anywhere. I want this since I don't want to create a custom page by myself.

**Is there a tutorial setting up an SPA to hook into AWS cognito login and signup pages? Like you would do with 0Auth.**

Lastly, I might have to create a custom sign in/signup page in the long run. However I the required information for each signin might vary. I might need email for one but email, name, phone number for others.

**What is the best way to design by custom signin/signup pages to dynamically access this information depending on the user pool**

Thanks in advance. This is more a question of pointing me to the correct documentation for custom and non custom signup/signin pages for SPAs.

Thanks again.

Comment: When you mention to AWS Cognito, are you referring to Cognito UserPools or Cognito Federated Identities or connecting both?

Comment: I want to authenticate my users (Userpools) with custom signin then I want to give those users particular access to AWS resources with identity pools. I am not 100% sure where federated identities comes into this.

Comment: For your use-case, you need to use both Userpools and Federated identities. Use AWS AmplifyJS library to simplify the SignUp and SignIn from SPA side (It supports both Angular and React).

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at this but I still can't find a good tutorial to do what I want. Any help?

Comment: Update: App integration in user pool and then https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html is what i'm looking for I think. Missed App integration since I set it up quickly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, you will need to connect Cognito UserPools (Use as the authentication provider) and Cognito Federated Identities (Used to provide AWS Resource access permission in exchange of Cognito UserPool token).

To simplify the authentication for SPA, you can use the [AWS AmplifyJS](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/index.html) library to simplify the integration.

Note: If you plan to implement a controlled SignUp process, consider implementing it with custom UI and for SignIn you can still use the Hosted UI solution.

For more details about Cognito UserPools vs Federated Identities refer the article [The Difference Between AWS Cognito UserPools and Federated Identities?](https://codeburst.io/the-difference-between-aws-cognito-userpools-and-federated-identities-9b47571795d4).